# The CPU utilization of an Oracle process is always 100%

Tags: oracle

CPU Usage for an Oracle Process is always 100%

See the SQL information about the process, but don't know what the SQL is for.
I want to know what this SQL is for?

Can this be turned off

[image: This is process information for top. Process number is 18020]

[image: This is the process related SQL information]

Comment: Are you sure that query is the one responsible for the performance, or was it just the process that was running the one time you looked?  You might want to check in GV$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY to see what SQL_IDs it's waiting on, and what the EVENTs are.

Comment: That query looks like something that a SQL IDE like TOAD etc. might invoke.  Kill that session and see what developer complains!